# Configuring REST WCF Service Over SSL

Tags: wcf, rest, ssl, https

I am building a WCF Restful Web Service and currently, I am transferring data over http. Now, I want to transfer the data securely over https. What shall I change in my config file to enable this please? This is my current config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService.DBService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IDBService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure transport layer security by defining a customized  and refer that in your endpoint using bindingConfiguration. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924478.aspx) out about configuring security. Once you have this configure an SSL certificate in your IIS to complete this. You can refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232.aspx) to see how to configure SSL certs with IIS.

Comment: is it possible to skip IIS? right now I am hosting the WCF service on my server

Comment: For selfhost you will have to configure your SSL certificate directly with HTTP.Sys using netsh. You can refer this article on how to configure SSL with selfhost. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24027/SSL-with-Self-hosted-WCF-Service